# How to debug program not opening in IDE?

Tags: c++, qt

I have about a dozen programs I'm making in QT creator, and one of them will not open in the IDE, meaning that if I open it from the command line, it runs fine, and gdb and valgrind don't find anything unusual.  But when I try to open it in QT creator I immediately get the error `program has unexpectedly finished`, and when I run it in debug mode I get this back trace:

```
 1    ??
 2    ??
 3    ??
 4    ??
 5    ??
 6    ??
 7    ??
 8    ??
 9    ??
10    ??
11    ??
12    ??
13    ??
14    ??
15    ??
16    ??
17    ??
18    glXGetFBConfigs
19    glXChooseFBConfigSIGX
20    ??
21    ??
22    ??
23    QXcbWindow::create()
24    QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow *) const
25    QWidgetPrivate::create(bool)
26    QWidgetPrivate::create_sys(unsigned long long, bool bool)
27    QWidget::create(unsigned long long, bool, bool)
28    QWidget::setVisible(bool)    
29    main                                                      main.cpp 62
```

What can I do about this? because I need the tracing tools...

Comment: Can you just run it in visual studio, and use the debugger?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I don't think so, I'm on ubuntu and visual studio code doesn't seem to be importing the project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after installing AMDGPU-PRO. QT Creator sets the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` before it runs the program you are developing. In the command line shell this variable is not set (at least on my computer, test with `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

To change this variable in QT Creator, click on the Projects icon. Select the project, then click on Build&Run and Run. Under "Run Environment" click on Details and select `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Clicking on Unset fixed the problem for me.

Apparently if you don't unset this variable, QT Creator adds a new directory to it whenever you add a library in the .pro file. If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` really needs this directory entry depends on whether the libary is in the standard library search path. On the command line you can test it with `ldconfig -p | grep <yourlib>`. Instead of unsetting the variable in QT Creator you can also edit it keeping the directories of the added libraries, and just remove `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.